# Как узнать что пользователь не скроллит?

Tags: jquery

Нашёл код, который определяет в каком направление скроллит пользователь (вверх или вниз)
Выглядит код так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event) {
    delta = parseInt(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail);
  });
});
```

Ну а дальше уже по `delta` определяем:

```
if(delta > 0) $('.text').text('вверх');
if(delta < 0) $('.text').text('вниз');
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как по этому (или другому) коду определять когда пользователь **не** скроллит страницу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант (тест не проводил).

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  var delta = 0;

  $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event) {
    delta = parseInt(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail);
  });

  setTimeout(function(){ 

 if(delta > 0) $('.text').text('вверх');
 if(delta < 0) $('.text').text('вниз');
 if(delta == 0) $('.text').text('не кручу, не вращаюсь');

 }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Работает, но мне нужно обновлять каждый раз.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 `.setTimeout()` замените на `.setInterval()`